# set и get в js выбрасывает ошибку

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, frontend, set

```
return {
                restrict:'A',
                controller:'fbFormObjectController',
                link:function (scope, element, attrs)
                {
                    var _form;
--> 724                 set form(value) {
                        this._form = value;
                    }

                    get form() {
                        return  this._form;
                    }
```

Есть такой кусок кода, при запуске:

> SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier form-builder.js:724:9
>
> Error:
>   [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?...и тд...

Что не так?

upd.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваши сетер и гетер случайно попали внутрь функции.

Comment: @igor нет, осмысленно нужно их там расположить, не знаю как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши сетер и гетер случайно попали внутрь функции.

```js
var a = {
  restrict: 'A',
  _form: null,
  set form(value) {
    this._form = value;
  },

  get form() {
    return this._form;
  }
}
a.form = "aaa";
console.log(a);
```

Comment: А внутри link: ... можно как-нибудь расположить?

Comment: @Lancelot Нет, нельзя. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: внутри функции нельзя располагать get и set получается?

Comment: @Lancelot Какой в этом смысл? `get` и `set` - операции свойств.Что они означают внутри функции?

Comment: Да, что они означают, для этого хочу зайти дебагом. Происходит вызов setter'a, но внутрь дебага setter'a я не попадаю

Comment: @Lancelot Я не понимаю, что Вы хотите сказать.

Comment: Я добавил изображение, там set есть console log и там нужно зайти дебагом.

Comment: значение изменяет, но в setter или getter не заходит. C debugger или через брейкпоинты не срабатывает